# Getting resources of library project in main project

Tags: android, android-resources, android-library

When I was having the project main_app, I was able to access the resources with-

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("xml/" + rule_file, "string", "com.main_app.main");
```

Now, my project main_app is the library project for the project test_app.

But when I run the test_app I always get the exception at -

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("xml/" + rule_file, "string", "com.main_app.main"); //Line 5456
```

**The error log -**

```
03-04 15:53:50.158: E/AndroidRuntime(29898): Caused by:
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
03-04 15:53:50.158: E/AndroidRuntime(29898):  at
android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1017) 03-04
15:53:50.158: E/AndroidRuntime(29898):    at
android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2102)
03-04 15:53:50.158: E/AndroidRuntime(29898):  at
android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:905) 03-04
15:53:50.158: E/AndroidRuntime(29898):    at
com.main_app.main.ClainFragment$23.run(ClainFragment.java:5456)
```

Comment: are they both project located at same location ?

Comment: @Kedarnath - yes same workspace.

Comment: instead of hardcode the package name use getPackageName()

Comment: @blackbelt - this was the real way..You saved the day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @blackbelt commented out,

The package name should be the package of project test_app that is the one we define in the manifest file of project test_app like -

```
 package="com.test_app.main"
```

So hardcoding with the line like -

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("xml/" + rule_file, "string", "com.main_app.main");
```

was wrong.

**Changed to** -

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("xml/" + rule_file, "string", getActivity().getPackageName());
```

It worked!